# It's not affect, but can you "effect" something?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, word-usage

I understand the differences between affect and effect, and generally when to use them. However, in some cases while reading I have seen authors use the phrase "effect a change" (among others) meaning, I think, to cause a change, or to bring about a change. Using "affect a change" seems wrong/awkward; so is this acceptable use?

Comment: No, "affect a change" is an error.

Comment: @tchrist I'd say many people affect change more often than they effect it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You effect a change when you cause the change to occur. When you are the one to bring the change about.

You affect a change when you change the change. When the change is already there and you influence it.

Comment: It would be interesting to test whether people who speak a dialect which doesn't distinguish between /ɪˈfɛkt/ and /əˈfɛkt/ are more likely to confuse them.

Comment: Here in the Bible Belt, they are often pronounced the same. That's not the worst, though. People say "are" for "our" and "ole" for "oil"/"bowl" for "boil", and it figuratively kills me.